# Retrieve all messages from mailbox

Tags: akka, message-queue

I want to implement a load-balancer actor, which can read all the messages in its message queue, and then take an action accordingly.

Is there any way to retrieve/extract the contents of all messages in the message queue, using the Java Api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, actors can only receive one message at a time.  If you need access to multiple messages in an actor, you can buffer them yourself in an internal queue (or whatever is appropriate) within your actor.